# Search in a two dimensional array and return the array list as a array

Tags: javascript

How can I search in a two dimensional array and return the array list as a array?

```
var dataSet = new Array(new Array());
function searchAsset(){
    dataSet.length = 0;
    var fileName = document.getElementById("fileName").value;
    var arr = new Array(["view_page.psd","test"],["ok_test.jpg","yes","kk"],["new_banner_2009.fla","good"],["gps-new-web.html","hot"]);
    var re = new RegExp(fileName ,'i');
    var res = null;
    for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            var newArr = arr[i][0];
            //alert(newArr+":"+newArr.match(re));
            var res = newArr.match(re);
        if(res != null){
            dataSet.push("["+arr[i]+"]");
        }
    }
    alert("Final --- "+dataSet);
    for(var m = 0;m<dataSet.length;m++){
        alert(dataSet[m]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't paste HTML, just the code, and use code formatting

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
var dataSet = new Array(new Array());
```

...is not a two-dimentional array. It results in an array with (initially) one element, which is a reference to another array with (initially) zero elements. The closest you'll come to a two-dimensional array in JavaScript is an array of arrays, such as:

```
function create2DArray(rows, columns) {
    var outer, index;

    outer = new Array(rows);
    for (index = 0; index < rows; ++index) {
        outer[index] = new Array(columns);
    }

    return outer;
}
```

Searching through such a thing is easy:

```
function find(thing, theArray) {
    var results, col, row, subArray;

    results = []; // Empty array
    for (row = 0; row < theArray.length; ++row) {
        subArray = theArray[row];
        for (col = 0; col < subArray.length; ++col) {
            value = subArray[col];
            if (value == thing) { // or whatever your criterion
                results.push({row: row, col: col});
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

That creates an array of objects, each with an `col` and `row` property, that tells you where the `thing`s in `theArray` are such that `theArray[row][col] == thing`.

Note that rather than doing `theArray[row][col]` every time in the loop, I grab the sub-array reference *once* for each row. Also note that since theoretically the sub-arrays could have different lengths, I don't assume they all have the same length.

I recommend reading up on JavaScript's arrays, which are fairly different from traditional arrays. They're really dictionaries, *associative* arrays, not contiguous blocks of memory indexed by an offset. When you do `theArray[5]`, you're looking up a *property* called "5" on the array in exactly the way that when you say `theObject['frog']` you're looking up a property "frog" on the object. (Not that implementations can't optimize that, but since JavaScript arrays are sparse, they have to be careful when doing so.)